# Save output of external program call in textfile in java

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I am using Windows!

I want to call a small .exe application from my java command line which is called "saucy.exe". It needs an input file "input.saucy". Both are stored in the correct directory.

When I use the command

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("saucy input.saucy");
```

everything works fine and I get an output on the console.

However, when I try to write the output in a file

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("saucy input.saucy > output.saucy");
```

nothing happens.

I already found the advice in http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html and tried to tokenize the command manually:

```
String[] cmd = {"saucy", "input.saucy > output.saucy"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

It is still not working. Any advice? It is no option for me to write the output to a file with java code, because its too slow.

Again: I am using Windows (I stress that because I read several hints for Linux systems).

Comment: `>` is a shell command, but you are not using one. try `String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/C", "saucy input.saucy > output.saucy" };`

Comment: Hi, this was the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: Added it as a answer so you can accepted by ticking on the left hand side. ;)

Comment: If you now yould give me an advice how i can execute the program, if it is in a folder (e.g. "folder"). I tried `String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/C", "folder/saucy input.saucy > output.saucy" };` and `String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/C", "folder\\saucy input.saucy > output.saucy" };` which gave me the error that: _application 'folder' could not been found._

Comment: When you give a relative path, it is relative to the current working directory.  If you don't know what that will be you need to give a full path like `C:\\basedirectory\\folder\\saucy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is a shell command, but you are not using one. try

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/C", "saucy input.saucy > output.saucy" };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 7 you can use the new [`ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.io.File%29) mechanism:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("saucy", "input.saucy");

// send standard output to a file
pb.redirectOutput(new File("output.saucy"));
// merge standard error with standard output
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getInputStream()`, `getOutputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` to retrieve the output (or send input).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html